# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{s^{k-1}}{k!}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+1} \frac{s^{k}}{k!}$, how it comes?

Tags: power-series, moment-generating-functions

In the following equation (From https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_1_3_moment_functions.php)

$$
\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber M_Y(s)&=\frac{e^s-1}{s}\\
\nonumber &=\frac{1}{s} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{s^k}{k!}-1\right)\\
\nonumber &=\frac{1}{s} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{s^k}{k!}\\
\nonumber &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{s^{k-1}}{k!}\\
\nonumber &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+1} \frac{s^{k}}{k!}.
\end{align}
$$

How the last two line equal?

Comment: This is just a shift on indices: if $k=1,2,...$ then $j:=k-1=0,1,...$ and $k!=(j+1)!=(j+1)\cdot j!.$

Comment: A good way to understand these expressions is to write out the first few terms with an ellipsis: Both are $s^0/0!+ s^1/1! + s^2/2! + \cdots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe do it in two steps
\begin{align}
\dots&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{s^{k-1}}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j+1} \frac{s^{j}}{j!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+1} \frac{s^{k}}{k!}.
\end{align}
For the first step write $k=j+1$ and note $(j+1)! = (j+1)\,j!$.
For the second step, relabel the dummy variable $j$ as $k$.